# How to chain this reduce and map function

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reduce

Both of these parameters are a list of objects. They both contain the property Name. I would like to project a few of their properties where the property Name are equal. The following gives the correct result. However, can someone help me refactor it to one traversal?

```
 export function fieldProjections(docTypeFields, recordFields) {
    const recordsByName = recordFields.reduce(function (rec, field) {
        rec[field.Name] = field;
        return rec;
    }, {});
    const fields = docTypeFields.map(dt => {
        return {
            'Name': dt.Name,
            'RawValue': recordsByName[dt.Name].RawValue,
            'Type': dt.DataType,
            'Value': recordsByName[dt.Name].Value,
            'Id': dt.DocumentTypeFieldID
        };
    });
    return fields;
}
```

Comment: *"refactor it to one traversal?"* - Why? The current code only traverses once per input array, so I don't see how you could traverse less than that. As an aside, the `.map()` callback could be tidied up if you used a single object literal to create all the properties at once.

Comment: It's not going to get much better than what you already have. But you could use a Map instead of a hash/"associative array".

Comment: I suppose a single traversal was a misnomer. I wanted to perform the above in a single expression.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let docTypeFields = [{Name: 'doc1', RawValue: '8', Type: 'large', Value: '3.50', Id: '1'},{Name: 'doc2', RawValue: '11', Type: 'medium', Value: '4.50', Id: '2'},{Name: 'doc3', RawValue: '81', Type: 'largish', Value: '3.60', Id: '3'},{Name: 'doc4', RawValue: '22', Type: 'small', Value: '2.50', Id: '4'}],
  recordFields = [{Name: 'doc1', Field: 'field1'},{Name: 'doc2', Field: 'field2'},{Name: 'doc3', Field: 'field3'},{Name: 'doc4', Field: 'field4'}];

docTypeFields.forEach(doc => {
    let siblingRecord = recordFields.find(record => record.Name === doc.Name);
    if (siblingRecord) doc.Field = siblingRecord.Field;
});

console.log(docTypeFields);
```

Comment: This results in *more* iterations than the OP's code. (And it mutates the input data.)

Comment: That's fair. I didn't notice that he wanted it in one traversal, and was simply trying to simplify the code. As for object mutation, it would be trivial to dupe each doc and store it in a new array (though I should have highlighted that I was modifying the docTypeFields).